# sqlalchemy fill part of query with added variable (using plus sign)

Tags: variables, flask, sqlalchemy

In database there are some tables named like `chest1, chest2, chest3, chest4, chest5 ...`.
For now my script is like:

```
if page == 1:
    chest = chest1.query.all()
elif page == 2:
    chest = chest2.query.all()
elif page == 3:
    chest = chest3.query.all()
elif page == 4:
    chest = chest4.query.all()
elif page == 5:
    chest = chest5.query.all()
```

I want to have something like:

```
chest = chest + page.query.all()
```

instead of using long if condition. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
tables = [chest1, chest2, chest3]

chest = tables[page-1].query.all()
```

So you have the list with table classes or objects and you can get the table you need using `page` as index.